# Hadoop - Kerberos Autentication

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, druid

I am configuring HDFS as deep storage for [Druid](http://druid.io/) and trying to figure out a way to pass kerberos keytab file for authentication.

Is there a Java System argument to pass the keytab file location?

Comment: Did you check that Druid "issue", especially the two **undocumented** env variables? https://github.com/druid-io/druid/issues/1588

Comment: @Samson - Yes but that doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Did you activate the debug mode of Kerberos, both at JAAS and Hadoop levels? cf. `-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true`and `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` as explained in https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html

Answer (score 0):

Shall we put the `keytab` file to `kinit` by `-t` parameter?

For example:
`kinit -t /path/to/keytab`

Comment: That would be `kinit -kt /path/to/keytab principal@REALM` with optional settings about "lifetime" and "renewal lifetime" -- e.g. if your ticket is valid for 8 hours *(usually capped at 10h by the KDC config anyway)* and renewable 2 days *(capped at 7d)* then you might **cron** a `kinit -kt blah blah` (ticket re-creation) every day at  "0 0 * * *" and a simple `kinit -R` (ticket renewal) at "0 6,12,18 * * *"